# Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use (LINQ)

Tags: c#, linq

I get this error `Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use.` when I run the code below.

Tables:
[image]

What am i missing?

```
    private void CopyAllPageObjects(int fromPageID, int toPageID)
    {
        CMSDataContext _db = new CMSDataContext();

        // Copy page objects
        var originalPageObjects = (from x in _db.CMSPageObjects
                                   where x.PageID == fromPageID
                                   select x);

        List<CMSPageObject> newPageObjects = new List<CMSPageObject>();
        foreach (CMSPageObject po in originalPageObjects)
        {
            CMSPageObject newPageObject = new CMSPageObject();
            newPageObject.PageID = toPageID;
            newPageObject.CMSObjectID = po.CMSObjectID;
            newPageObject.Name = po.Name;
            newPageObject.Sorting = po.Sorting;
            newPageObjects.Add(newPageObject);

            // Copy page object attribute values
            var originalPoavs = (from x in _db.CMSPageObjectAttributeValues
                                 where x.CMSPageObjectID == po.ID
                                 select x);

            List<CMSPageObjectAttributeValue> newPoavs = new List<CMSPageObjectAttributeValue>();
            foreach (CMSPageObjectAttributeValue poav in originalPoavs)
            {
                CMSPageObjectAttributeValue newPoav = new CMSPageObjectAttributeValue();
                newPoav.CMSAttributeID = poav.CMSAttributeID;
                newPoav.CMSPageObjectID = newPageObject.ID;
                newPoav.LCID = poav.LCID;
                newPoav.Value = poav.Value;
                newPoavs.Add(newPoav);
            }
            _db.CMSPageObjectAttributeValues.InsertAllOnSubmit(newPoavs);
        }

        _db.CMSPageObjects.InsertAllOnSubmit(newPageObjects);
        _db.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

Comment: which line throws error?

Comment: I guess `newPoav.CMSPageObjectID = newPageObject.ID;` throws the error.

Comment: I have updated the question with my table layout.

Comment: I have removed all code from `// Copy page object attribute values` to `_db.CMSPageObjectAttributeValues.InsertAllOnSubmit(newPoavs);` and that is working as it should. So guess it is something inside that code that is messed up.

Comment: cant you debug and see where exactly in code you getting error?

Comment: When i debug, it stops on `_db.SubmitChanges();`.

Comment: `newPageObject.ID` is set before setting to `newPoav.CMSPageObjectID`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to add an object, while another one with same primary key exists. Are `PageID` or `CMSObjectID` primary keys? Or `CMSAttributeID`?

You might also want to share more data about how your data tables look like.

Update: after you added database struct, I would look closer at this line:

```
newPoav.CMSPageObjectID = newPageObject.ID;
```

the `newPageObject.ID` is probably not known at this time, because you didn't add the object to the DB yet (I suspect `ID` is identity). I think you could use:

```
newPoav.CMSPageObject = newPageObject
```

Answer (score 4):

I was getting this error and it was because I had forgotten to set the Primary Key field in the database to "Identity Specification" (auto-increment). But that is just a guess

Answer (score 2):

Seems you are missing primary key or an unique key on CMSPageObject table. Please try to verify the keys in the database. I had same issue since I had missed the PK on the table.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add some code just for testing if the list `newPoavs` have a key exist already in the database

you can just add this

```
        foreach (CMSPageObjectAttributeValue poav in originalPoavs)
        {
            CMSPageObjectAttributeValue newPoav = new CMSPageObjectAttributeValue();
            newPoav.CMSAttributeID = poav.CMSAttributeID;
            newPoav.CMSPageObjectID = newPageObject.ID;
            newPoav.LCID = poav.LCID;
            newPoav.Value = poav.Value;
            newPoavs.Add(newPoav);
            if(_db.CMSPageObjectAttributeValues.Any(x=>x.LCID == newPoav.LCID & x.CMSAttributeID == newPoav.CMSAttributeID & x.CMSPageObjectID == newPoav.CMSPageObjectID ))
            MessageBox.Show("Already exist");
        }
```

just to test your values